# How to set in a Report the format date in TextBox based current RegionalSetting?

Tags: visual-studio, date, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have in my *Report*, I'm using Visual Studio *Ultimate 2013* a *TextBox* with **DATE** value

[image: TextBOX]

I would like to set the DATE *format* by current *Regional Setting*.

So : if is US I wold like to set format yyyy/mm/dd etc..
There is a possible way in *Visual Studio*. There is a specific property or formula ?

I need to set dynamically the date format.

Thanks!

Comment: I would think that this is not possible. Since this is not an intended usecase. Maybe you could add a parameter, which controls diffrent format option in an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to navigate to Text box properties > Number > Date. Select any date format which begins with asterisk(*) as it denotes that regional settings will be applied. You can refer to the screenshot below for details

[image: Regional date format screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @Usama Aziz, work well. I share with tou another Report Date information about print.